# qt. how to get a graphics item by position (x & y value)

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

I drew some rectangles on a graphics view in qt creator. Now I want to get a rectangle to change its color and something else by its known position. Is it possible? I don't want to use for loop to check every rectangle's position. Is there an easy way?
Thank you in the advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[QGraphicsScene::itemAt()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsscene.html#itemAt) will return the item at the given location.